# Issue on file size and custom Web Service

Tags: web-services

I'm facing a problem with web services in a IIS + Sharepoint farm...

I have a Web service that receives a byte[] and convert it to a file on the Sharepoint System. When I upload a file from the system I found no problem with file (till 50MB), when I load with my WS the call is leaved unless it is < 4MB.

I tried to modify the web.config:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200"/> //KB => 50MB
```

and then:

```
<security> 
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" > 
     <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" /> 
  </requestFiltering> 
</security>
```

do an IISReset but nothing has change: byte[] > 4MB is not accepted..

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You have to increase max upload file in sharepoint central admin too in order to succeed.
[Microsoft Support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925083) have an article about the problem you are facing.

Comment: Already 50MB...